# What mistake is in the code since does not work

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel workbook, 14 columns are there C to P with range C1:P200 Row 1 contains time value. Example: C1=9/27/2014 8:42:34 AM; D1=9/27/2014 9:12:25 AM & so on...till P1.

Output required: C2:C200 should become FORMULA FREE IMMEDIATELY & leave the value when system's time>=C1 Similarly, D2:200 should become FORMULA FREE & leave the value when system's time>=D1 & so on till column P i.e. P2:P200 should become FORMULA FREE & leave the value when system's time>=P1

ThisWorkbook code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P1")
        Application.OnTime cl.Value, "'ConvertFormulasToValues """ & cl.Range("A2:A199").Address & """'"
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Then I Created a Sub as follows:

```
Private Sub ConvertFormulasToValues(RngToConvertAddress As String)
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(RngToConvertAddress)
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

WHAT MISTAKE I AM DOING SINCE THE CODE DOES NOT WORK AS PER REQUIREMENT.

Comment: "does not work as per requirement" means what *exactly* ?  And there's no need to SHOUT here.

Comment: Requirement:C2:C200 should become FORMULA FREE IMMEDIATELY & leave the value when system's time>=C1 Similarly, D2:200 should become FORMULA FREE & leave the value when system's time>=D1 & so on till column P i.e. P2:P200 should become FORMULA FREE & leave the value when system's time>=P1

Comment: i think the question is clear. But dont know about the shouting thing. So upvoted and gave an answer.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things:

a. Removing the word `Private` before your `Sub` might be the solution!

b. you mentioned 14 columns are C to P. But your code contain `Range("A1:P1")` should it not be `Range("C1:P1")` ?

By the way, you should post if any error messages come in the process.

APPENDED :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim cl As Range

For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:P1")
Application.OnTime cl.Value, "'ConvertFormulasToValues """ & cl.Range("A2:A199").Address & """'"  
Next cl
End Sub
```

AND

```
Sub ConvertFormulasToValues(RngToConvertAddress As String)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(RngToConvertAddress)
rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

**APPENDED Image : Range.Range Explanation**

[image: Range.Range Explanation]

Comment: Private Module also works if calling and called subroutines are in the same module

Comment: @sam, calling place is Thisworkbook section, so called sub should not be there. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the following in a "Module" and change `Private` to `Public`:

```
Public Sub ConvertFormulasToValues(RngToConvertAddress As String)
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(RngToConvertAddress)
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

The following can stay under "ThisWorkbook":

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P1")
        Application.OnTime cl.Value, "'ConvertFormulasToValues """ & cl.Range("A2:A199").Address & """'"
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Tested it and works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub t()

For Each cell In Range("c1:p1")
    If Now >= cell.Value Then
        Call timer1(cell.Column)
    End If
 Application.CutCopyMode = false
 Range("c1").select

Next cell

End Sub


Sub timer1(col As Integer)
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(199, col)).Copy
    .Cells(2, col).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sam, please elaborate WHERE this code needs to be pasted: as Worksheet event code; ThisWorkbook or Module?

Comment: Sam, Code works but only 1 action needs to be rectified: After getting triggered at the 'cut-off' time, cell P2:P199 (which is the last data column) is covered by a 'border'.  This covering of P2:P199 is not required & hence some modification needs to be done in the code.

Comment: Sam, If I am clearer again: The code works but after triggering at the time as it should do, a range P2:P199 gets automatically 'selected' i.e. P2:P199 gets covered by 'marching ants' around the edge.  Kindly remove this last action by the code by modifying it.  Can the cursor be made to stay at C2?

Comment: I have updated my code..and apologies for replying late

Comment: That WORKS sam.  I have pasted this code in a ws with tab named 'F24'.  There are 2 more ws in the Excel workbook with tab named 'A4' & '7'.  'A4' contains code as Worksheet event code & '7' updates using real time feeds. My question: Will the new code in 'F24' affect working of either of 'A4' or '7'?

Comment: Yes it will as long the range is in c1:p1. If range changes then you have to update with correct range refrence.

Comment: Will this be a solution: If I move C1:P199 of 'F24' to 'extreme' right i.e. GC1:GP199.  'A4' & '7' does not have any value/(s) in GC1:GP199 in their respective worksheets.  What I need is: The new code in 'F24' SHOULD BE SYNTAXED such that it should not hamper the working of the code in 'A24'. Note: There is no code in '7' but it gets RTD.

Comment: this is for you to figure out. I can not do the spoon feeding..Take some efforts and resolve it by yourself

Comment: sam, for this project, I had written 3 more codes.  But all 3 have slight problem; First one:Makes the whole workbook 'jammed'; Second one: removes formula before C1's time; Third one: does not remove formula from column D.  So like got stuck & asked you a remedial action for achieving the result immediately & not to dis please you.

Comment: sam zat Below code is removing formulas from range when system's time<row#1's time(WRONG).Code s remove formulas & retain values in cells when system's time>=row#1's time.Rectification in code can work. Sub ConvertOldFormulasToValues()
   Dim oCell as Range
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   For Each oCell in Worksheets("TheSheet").Range("C2:P200")
       If oCell.Value < Date + Time Then
         oCell.Value = oCell.Value
       End If
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Comment: Sub ConvertOldFormulasToValues()
   Dim oCell as Range
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   For Each oCell in Worksheets("TheSheet").Range("C2:P200")
       If oCell.Value < Date + Time Then
         oCell.Value = oCell.Value
       End If
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub